# Interactive output in blender

Tags: export, game-engine

I am learning how to use blender. After I create an animation in blender, how do I send the output from a blender application so that it remains interactive?

I mean, I can save as `.exe` but it is not interactive. How do I create a standalone file that has buttons to fast-forward and rewind the movie and change the camera view when I do something like dragging with mouse?

**EDIT**
I have an animation in blender. I want to export a standalone player with buttons/features that can change angle of view and do something like change frame rate of animation, or such stuff.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused as to what exactly you want to do.

As far as outputting as an .exe with interactivity, you'd have to render out frames for ever possible outcome and then find a software that can manage each of those.

For interactive scenes in Blender, you'd really have to use the game engine, which uses a real-time renderer, unlike Blender's which renders out static data files with image information to files for later viewing.

Comment: Could you give more details - what is the propose of this? If you send someone an executable, you could also send them blender which defaults to loading your scene with the '3D View Full' screen (so no interface distractions), giving them basic instructions on the view-port and switching cameras.

Comment: See also the answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10464/3515. [Blend4Web](http://www.blend4web.com) natively supports many Blender-specific features - node editor, NLA animation, particle system, Bullet physics and others

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rendering an animation will create a movie file(or a string of .pngs) which is not an interactive format. It sounds like you want to create an interactive application with the Blender Game engine.

To export a Blender Game (as an Windows exe or Mac app):

- Create the game using the Blender Game engine(which can be selected in the render engine dropdown). I'm not going to explain how to create the game, but there are tons of resources available.
- Enable the "Save Game as Runtime" addon.
- Go to File > Export > Save Game as Runtime

Answer (score 2):

There is also the [Three.JS](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender) exporter by Mr Doob which can output a version of your animation that can be played in any WebGL capable browser. Here's an example of animation exported to [Three.js](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada_keyframe.html) . This method does require some understanding of JavaScript, if you want to customize it to have WASD-like controls.