# Blender Output Options

Tags: export

I'm new to blender and have just built my first 3D model. I'm wondering though if there is any way to create a properly rendered output of the 3D model in a standalone file which another user could open on their computer and have the ability to move the camera (zoom, pan, rotate etc) around? Or even if not standalone just a program that creates the rendered model and allows the user to have full camera control after the object has been rendered (rather than just getting a video/image output of the model).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you create a specific setup using the Game Engine where the camera has controls for this, it is not possible to do so out of the box with Blender. Also, in my opinion, it is not entirely worth the trouble doing this as there are better ways to go about it. From experience, such a setup can quickly get clunky as there are performance issues across platforms and other things you might need to take into consideration.

---

I would instead recommend going with a browser solution. By doing this, you only need export once to some supported mesh format such as `.fbx` or `.obj` and there are very little to no dependencies *(game engine standalones tend to be a bit large)*, the user just needs to have a modern web browser.

See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1055/12) and there is also [p3d.in](http://p3d.in/) *(I highly recommend this site)* and [Sketchfab](http://sketchfab.com/). Example of a [model on p3d.in](http://p3d.in/t2BFT). It also supports textures and several other rendering options.